# Посчитать сумму в html таблице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как посчитать сумму только тех ячеек из строки в которой есть значения в другой ячейке.

У меня есть таблица

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Мне нужно получичть сумму 1 + 3 = 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dao jQuery:

```js
let sum = 0;
$("table td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "+") {
    sum += parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('td:first-child').html());
  }
})

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var summ = 0;
    for (let i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
        var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (let z=0;z<td.length;z++){
            if (z+1 < td.length) {
                if (td[z + 1].innerText) {
                    summ += +td[z].innerText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(summ);
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td><span class="check">+</span></td></tr>
</table>
```